# Firefox incorrectly adding margin-bottom to the top of an element

Tags: html, css, firefox, margin

In Firefox, when I add the following CSS rules, the `75px` margin bottom is also applied to the top of `#header-container`. Firebug isn't reporting this, but the element has moved down the page by the exact amount of the margin-bottom. Other browsers don't do this.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to stop it? Thanks.

```
#header-container{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 75px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Can't recreate [http://jsfiddle.net/7dbpE/](http://jsfiddle.net/7dbpE/)

Comment: never knew margin: 0 auto 75px; worked. did you try with individual margin rules? like margin-top: 0; margin-right/margin-left: auto; margin-bottom: 75px;

Comment: Are you using a reset style sheet?

Comment: Sounds like it might be *margin collapse*.  Without a demo, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Morpheus - I cannot recreate using just the CSS above either, suggesting it is something else that is causing the problem. A little extreme, but here is your fiddle with the HTML output from a page that is causing trouble, along with the complete CSS. I'd be greatful if you could take a look at that. Thanks. [http://jsfiddle.net/7dbpE/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/7dbpE/4/)

Comment: Everything is working how it should do. Top margin is in `#main-container { margin: 40px auto 0;}` My firefox version is 20.0.1

Comment: Strange, for me it is not. Top margin is 75px, the same as the bottom margin of `#header-container`. Again though, Firebug is not reporting that margin, but it is there. I am also on version 20.0.1. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how and why this is happening, but if you change `#header-container {margin-bottom: 75px; float: left;}`, this will fix the issue :)

Comment: Ha, that does indeed fix it. There seems to be no rhyme or reason for this, I guess it's just a FF bug. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @David Gard always glad to help :)

Comment: @Morpheus - Can you add it as an answer, I'll then accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how and why this is happening, but if you change your `#header-container` styling to this

```
#header-container{
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 75px;
   width: 960px;
   float: left;
}
```

it will fix the issue.